# Eigenvalues of $AA^T$ for random circulant $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-matrices

Consider a random circulant $n\times n$ $0$-$1$ matrix $A$. Let the probability $P(A_{1,i} = 1) = 1/\sqrt{n}$  and all the elements of the first row be probabilistically independent.

We know that the expected value of the diagonal elements of $S=AA^T$ is $\sqrt{n}$ and that the off-diagonal have mean $1$.

> If $n$ is large, what can we say about the eigenvalues of $S$?

In particular, numerically one can see that the mean eigenvalue is $\sqrt{n}$?  How can one prove this?

Comment: I dont understand how are compatible 1) the fact that all the coefficients are random and 2) The fact that the diagonal elements of $AA^T$ are deterministic. Could you explain it, even on a $3 \times 3$ example ?

Comment: @JeanMarie You are right. The inner product $<x.x>$ is equal to the number of 1s in $x$ which is on average $\sqrt{n}$ in my case. I will fix the question.

Comment: A track, may be: $A=Fdiag(\lambda_1...\lambda_n)F^{-1}$ where $F$ is the $n \times n$ matrix or Discrete Fourier Transform, and $\lambda_1...\lambda_n$ the Discrete Fourier Transform of the first line https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix . This would transfer the issue "the other side of the mirror"...

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "the mean eigenvalue". Is it the mean of all the eigenvalues of a given matrix, i.e. $\frac{\operatorname{tr}A}n$, averaged over the whole sample space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mean eigenvalue follows pretty easily from the work you've done. As you mentioned, the diagonal elements of $S$ are identical and equal to the sum of 1's in the vector that defines the circulant matrix

$$S_{ii} \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,1/\sqrt{n}) $$

From the linearity of the expectation, the expected mean eigenvalue is:

$$E(\lambda(S))=E\left(\frac{\operatorname{tr} (S)}{n}\right)=E(S_{ii})=\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: That's much simpler than I realised! Thank you.